# ¿Para que sirve esta instancia en la herencia prototípica? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Me encuentro realizando un curso y he llegado a la parte donde me presentan este código.

```
function Perro(nombre, genero, tamanio){
  this.super = Animal;                  
  this.super(nombre, genero)       
  this.tamanio = tamanio;
}

Perro.prototype = new Animal();
Perro.prototype.constructor = Perro;

let Doky = new Perro("Doky", "Macho", "14cm");
console.log(Doky);
```

Mis preguntas son las siguientes:

1. Por qué necesito declarar el prototype y el constructor? Si la "herencia" ya funciona correctamente.
2. Por qué cuanod establezco el valor del prototype lo ejecuto colocando "()" mientras que al establecer el constructor NO.
3. El del tutorial menciona que tenemos que hacer esto porque así no se duplica la información. Sin embargo, según yo lo entiendo lo único que hace es duplicar la instancia de Animal -una en la función Perro y otra afuera en el prototipo-. De esta manera, igual se sigue repitiendo la instancia dentro de la función es decir:

   this.super = Animal;
   this.super(nombre, genero)

Cada vez que se instancia un objeto nuevo de Perro. Agradecería bastante su ayuda :)!

Vídeo de donde saco la duda: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-m7xtwvH1E&list=PLvq-jIkSeTUZ6QgYYO3MwG9EMqC-KoLXA&index=24&ab_channel=jonmircha"

Comment: Tampoco me queda claro para qué sirve (si es que de algo sirve). En todo caso, una clase puede ser una [extensión de otra](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends), con un código más legible y entendible.